# How to create shortcut icon for java program

Tags: java, swing

Hi I have created executable jar of my java program i want to create shortcut icon for that jar. Means may be my jar is in any other memory location of hard drive(eg- D or E drive for windows) but my icon must be at Desktop. So that if i double click on icon from desktop then my application will start.
How to create this

Thanks
Sunil Kumar Sahoo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to look around for Java Windows Installers, they have functionality to create desktop shortcuts. Take a look at this [article](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/java.html) and [this](http://www.esus.com/docs/GetIndexPage.jsp?uid=397) one too.

[Install4J](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/install4j/features.html) is my personal favorite

Answer (score 19):

**100% Working native windows shortcut for jar execution:**

First create regular windows shortcut (right click on desktop, **new** -> **shortcut**)
In text field "*Type the location of the item*" write: 
**"C:\path\to\javaw.exe" -jar "C:\path\to\jar\myExecutableJar.jar"**

[image]

Click **next**, type shortcut name ant press **Finish**.

That's all! :)

Then You can set custom icon:

Right click on **shortcut** -> **Properties** -> **Change Icon...**

[image]

Comment: What do you mean? Why not?

Comment: I can create shortcut on the desktop but it does not start the java GUI application. It just open and close the window immediately. Try to run Regular Expression Tester (or any other GUI program) from wiztools.org

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to create shortcut as normal.

After all, installing Java on Windows should by default allow you to run .jar files directly; there should be an association of that extension to java.exe. Alternatively, you can create a batch file to run the jar and then create the shortcut for that file.

Answer (score 3):

1. right click on desktop select option new - shortcut
2. click on brows button and select path of jar file
3. select next - finish  button.
4. shortcut file is created on desktop . right click on shortcut file
5. select properties
6. click on change icon and change icon of file

Congratulations you created a shortcut

Answer (score 1):

There is a JNI library named jshortcut-0.4-oberzalek.jar ,you can download it from this link just given below and add  to your project libraries.

https://github.com/jimmc/jshortcut/downloads

It works unbelievably perfect in my project.Here I use an additional function named getdir(),to get current location of your deployed project folder, and store value in a  variable named 'PRJT_PTH'.

After that your deployed project can save on any drive,no matter where it is.It will  automatically creates a shortcut on desktop

Here is the code that I used for creating a shortcut to deployed project.(JMM.jar in my case)

```
import net.jimmc.jshortcut.JShellLink;

String PRJT_PATH="";
private void getdir() throws IOException{
    File f=new File(".");
    File[] f1=f.listFiles();
    PRJT_PATH=f.getCanonicalPath();
}    //you can call this function at windowOpened event,this will get path of current directory where your project located.

JShellLink link;
String filePath;

public void createDesktopShortcut() { //after that call createDesktopShortcut() function to create shortcut to desktop.
    try {
        link = new JShellLink();
        filePath = JShellLink.getDirectory("") + PRJT_PTH +"\\JMM.jar";
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    try {
        link.setFolder(JShellLink.getDirectory("desktop"));
        link.setName("JMM");  //Choose a name for your shortcut.In my case its JMM.
        link.setPath(filePath); //link for our executable jar file
        link.setIconLocation(PRJT_PATH1+ "\\jmm.ico"); //set icon image(before that choose your on manual icon file inside our project folder.[jmm.ico in my case])
        link.save();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
       ex.getmessage();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If Java is properly installed, the JAR extension is assigned to java. That means on commandline you can type

```
C:> myprogram.jar
```

And if your jar is properly build that runs the program.

You can copy/paste-link your JAR file to desktop.

Answer (score 0):

This is a short tutorial for creating shortcuts to existing programs: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/140443

Answer (score 0):

Assume your jar file is in location c:\pgm\abc.jar

open notepad and type 
c:
cd\
cd  pgm
java -jar abc.jar

Then save that notepad document as "anyname.bat"

Then create  a shortcut for that batch file (ie...right click that file and click "Create Shortcut"). You can use this shortcut to run your jar file.

Answer (score 0):

Creating shortcut for java .class file is very easy, just follow the instructions:

1. create a .class file using javac
2. open a notepad and type following line (note: here filename is the name of my file. Type your file name without .java or .class )

   ```
    java  filename
    pause
   ```

   3.save it as anyname.bat in the same folder where your .class file resides
   4.copy and paste shortcut of your new file

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure about this answer, but I've recently found this:

```
    try {
        Files.createLink(FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("C:/Documents and Settings/MyUser/Desktop", "MyLink.lnk")
                , FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("C:/Documents and Settings/MyUser/Desktop", "MyExistingFile.pdf"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This example create a link (shortcut) in the desktop to another file in the desktop.

it in deed creates a shortcut recognized by the OS, but I have not been able to make it work in Windows systems (the shortcut is been created and it is recognized by Windows but it does not work), but I'm working on it, so as soon as I get the answer I'll post it here, in the meantime, you may try to help me, lets see who is the first to make it work :D!

Greetings!

Comment: *"lets see who is the first to make it work"*  [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) beat you to it in around Java 1.2 or Java 1.3.  And the JWS desktop icon is cross-platform for any OS That allows desktop icons.  ;)  More recent JREs allow for the creation of an icon at run-time - see the [`IntegrationService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/IntegrationService.html).

Comment: hahahah well it seams I'm many steps behind the java programmers XD, but is good to know that I won't have to reinvent the wheel

Answer (score 0):

### To do this:

- Right click in the destination folder(for the shortcut)
- Click `New -> Shortcut`
- In "Type the location of the item" enter `java -jar`***your jar path(full)***
- Click next end enter a name
- It should now work!

---

### You can change the icon of your shortcut, too:

- Right click -> Properties -> Shortcut -> Change Icon